# Formula - profit and loss - purchasing same number of articles at different rates and selling them

Tags: linear-algebra

> A dealer purchases a certain number of articles at $x$ articles for a
>   rupee and the same number at $y$ articles for a rupee. He mixes them
>    together and sells at $z$ articles for a rupee. Then his gain or loss
>    percentage$=([2xy-1]/z(x+y)) \times 100$; according to positive or negative sign
>
> [source:freshersworld.com](http://placement.freshersworld.com/quantitative-aptitude-questions-and-answers/profit-and-loss/331118598)

During my studies, i came across this formula. However, I believe this formula is not correct. My attempt gave me a different result, as given below.

> cost price of $n$ objects having rate  $x$ articles for a rupee
>   $=\dfrac{n}{x}$
>
> cost price of $n$ objects having rate  $y$ articles for a rupee
>   $=\dfrac{n}{y}$
>
> So, total cost price of $2n$ articles
>   $=\dfrac{n}{x}+\dfrac{n}{y}=\dfrac{n(x+y)}{xy}$
>
> total selling price of $2n$ articles $=\dfrac{2n}{z}$
>
> profit/loss =
>   $\dfrac{2n}{z}-\dfrac{n(x+y)}{xy}=\dfrac{2nxy-nz(x+y)}{xyz}$
>
> profit/loss percentage $=\dfrac{\dfrac{2nxy-nz(x+y)}{xyz} \times
>  100}{\dfrac{n(x+y)}{xy}}$ $=\dfrac{2xy-z(x+y)}{z(x+y)} \times 100$

Need your help in confirming whether the formula obtained as a result of my calculations is right or wrong. if i am wrong and the formula given by the site is right, please tell me why my calculations are wrong. thanks.

Comment: You are right. The book should have written $=[2xy/(z(x+y))-1] \times 100$

Comment: @trueblueanil, thanks for clarifying.